# Remove item from array when cleared from AutoComplete component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, material-ui

I am using Material UI's AutoComplete component where I create n number of TextFields based on the headcount from the rows object. I am having trouble updating the state of the *associateList* when the TextField is cleared. Also, it would be greatly appreciated if I could get guidance on how to remove the associate from *associateOptions* when the user gets added/removed from the TextField. I attempted this, but I kept getting an error about the item not existing in the associateOptions.

```
import { Autocomplete, Paper, Table, TableBody, TableCell, TableContainer, TableHead, TableRow, TextField } from '@mui/material';
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const rows = [
  { processPath: 'Role 1', headcount: 2 },
  { processPath: 'Role 2', headcount: 1 },
  { processPath: 'Role 3', headcount: 3 },
  { processPath: 'Role 4', headcount: 2 },
  { processPath: 'Role 5', headcount: 2 },
];

export const EmployeesByPath: React.FC = () => {
  const associateOptions = ['john', 'kevin', 'sally', 'mark'];
  // const [associateOptions, setAssociateOptions] = useState<string[]>(['john', 'kevin', 'sally', 'mark']);
  const [associateList, setAssociateList] = useState<Record<string, string[] | undefined>>({});

  const getAssociatesByProcessPath = (processPath: string): string[] => {
    return associateList[processPath] ?? [];
  };

  //   const handleAssociateRemove = (processPath: string, associateIndex: number): void => {
  //     setAssociateList((prevAssociateList) => ({
  //       ...prevAssociateList,
  //       [processPath]: [...getAssociatesByProcessPath(processPath).filter((_, i) => i !== associateIndex)],
  //     }));
  //   };

  const handleSelection = (processPath: string, associateIndex: number, associate: string | null): void => {
    setAssociateList((prevAssociateList) => {
      const updatedAssociateList = getAssociatesByProcessPath(processPath);

      if (associate) {
        updatedAssociateList[associateIndex] = associate;
      } else {
        updatedAssociateList.filter((_, i) => i !== associateIndex);
      }

      return {
        ...prevAssociateList,
        [processPath]: updatedAssociateList,
      };
    });
  };

  console.log(associateList);

  return (
    <>
      <TableContainer component={Paper} sx={{ minWidth: 800 }}>
        <Table>
          <TableHead>
            <TableRow>
              <TableCell>Process Path</TableCell>
              <TableCell>Associate Login</TableCell>
            </TableRow>
          </TableHead>
          <TableBody>
            {rows.map((row, rowIndex) => (
              <TableRow
                key={rowIndex}
                sx={{
                  '&:last-child td, &:last-child th': { border: 0 },
                }}>
                <TableCell style={{ width: '35%' }}>{row.processPath}</TableCell>
                <TableCell style={{ width: '45%' }} component='th' scope='row'>
                  {[...Array(row.headcount)].map((_: undefined, index: number) => (
                    <Autocomplete
                      //   disablePortal
                      sx={{ maxWidth: '240px', marginBottom: 1 }}
                      key={`roles-${index}`}
                      id='employeesList'
                      options={associateOptions}
                      onChange={(__, associate) => handleSelection(row.processPath, index, associate)}
                      renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label={`Select an associate`} variant='outlined' />}
                    />
                  ))}
                </TableCell>
              </TableRow>
            ))}
          </TableBody>
        </Table>
      </TableContainer>
    </>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're trying to manage a list of associates for each process path and want to remove an associate when it's cleared from the Autocomplete component. In your handleSelection function, the logic for removing an associate seems to have an issue. Here's how you can modify it to properly remove associates:

```
const handleSelection = (processPath: string, associateIndex: number, associate: string | null): void => {
  setAssociateList((prevAssociateList) => {
    const updatedAssociateList = [...getAssociatesByProcessPath(processPath)]; // Clone the array

    if (associate !== null) {
      updatedAssociateList[associateIndex] = associate;
    } else {
      updatedAssociateList.splice(associateIndex, 1); // Remove the associate at associateIndex
    }

    return {
      ...prevAssociateList,
      [processPath]: updatedAssociateList,
    };
  });
};
```